# Any better way to flatten and rebuild nested dict

Tags: python, dictionary

One solution posted by myself, but I'm not satisfied with it, which is too complicated.

Sometimes, we need to flatten one dict, and sometimes in reverse, for example:
a nested dict looks like this:

```
{'a': 'A', 'b': {'c': 'BC', 'd': [4, 44, 444]}}
```

and a flatten dict:

```
{'a': 'A', 'b__c': 'BC', 'b__d': [4, 44, 444]}
```

as we can see, in this case, we use double underscore to represent the nested level.

**I wrote two functions to do these, Please check the answer I posted, but I still prefer any robost 3rd party lib or any other idea to make these two functions eaiser?**

And **besides**, I also wanna know what is the right way to flatten value, which type is a list filled with dict objects? Let's put it this way, what should a flatten dict should be, if we replace the number 4, 44, 444 with dicts intead.

Comment: Asking for a 3rd party library is [explicitly off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site. Please re-word or delete your question.

Comment: As Rory pointed out, this is off-topic. But I'm curious what your use use case is for the data structure you show second. Seeing `b__c` and `b__d` as keys gives me an uneasy feeling in my gut, and makes me wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Didn't you guys meet cases like this? when passing json from API, we got flatten json.

Comment: @MenglongLi, why would you have to flatten the JSON? That format supports nested objects, exactly as you show in your first example.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I've already tried to write my own functions to handle this case, why down-vote my question?

Comment: @Chris, when handling some API, facebook's API for instance, which could contain very big json, and you only care about some fields, so you pass-in the fileds you're interested, and the API will return the related json, which is flatten, but using double underscore, so you got what you want, and you can also know the original structure, with a quite lightweight json.

Comment: @MenglongLi, we don't know for sure that Rory downvoted the question. But he _did_ explain why this is off-topic on Stack Overflow. If he downvoted that's probably the reason.

Comment: Yes, I did downvote your question. As I commented, your question as written is clearly off-topic. It can be re-written to get it back on-topic, by removing the request for a 3rd-party library and showing some work in the question. You can decide how to change the question, but it should be changed. If you disagree, please explain why, but address the issue I raised.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, thx, yeah, the first post answer is from myself. Also change the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote two functions to convert flatten and nested dict, but I prefer to find some robost lib to handle these cases.

```
def flatten(nested_dict, result=None, prefix=''):
    from collections import OrderedDict
    if result is None:
        result = dict()
    for k, v in nested_dict.items():
        new_k = '__'.join((prefix, k)) if prefix else k
        if not (isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, OrderedDict)):
            result.update({new_k: v})
        else:
            flatten(v, result, new_k)
    return result


def rebuild(flatten_dict, result=None):
    from collections import defaultdict
    import json

    def tree():
        return defaultdict(tree)

    def rec(keys_iter, value):
        _r = tree()
        try:
            _k = next(keys_iter)
            _r[_k] = rec(keys_iter, value)
            return _r
        except StopIteration:
            return value

    if result is None:
        result = dict()

    for k, v in flatten_dict.items():
        keys_nested_iter = iter(k.split('__'))
        cur_level_dict = result
        while True:
            try:
                k = next(keys_nested_iter)
                if k in cur_level_dict:
                    cur_level_dict = cur_level_dict[k]
                else:
                    cur_level_dict[k] = json.loads(json.dumps(rec(keys_nested_iter, v)))
            except StopIteration:
                break

    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_dict = {'a': 'A',
               'b':
                   {
                       'd': [4, 44, 444],
                       'c': 'BC'
                   }
               }

    my_flatten_dict = flatten(my_dict)
    assert my_flatten_dict == {'a': 'A', 'b__c': 'BC', 'b__d': [4, 44, 444]}

    my_nested_dict = rebuild(my_flatten_dict)
    assert my_nested_dict == {'a': 'A', 'b': {'c': 'BC', 'd': [4, 44, 444]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this **isn't** something you should do, but you can use a `json.dumps` to change it to a string and use `re.sub` to do the operation

```
import json, re
d = {'a': 'A', 'b': {'c': 'BC', 'd': [4, 44, 444]}}
def flatten(to_flat):
    return json.loads(re.sub('\}+','}',re.sub('":? *\{"', '__', json.dumps(d))))
print(flatten(d))
# prints {'a': 'A', 'b__c': 'BC', 'd': [4, 44, 444]}
```

But there's a problem with the `rebuilt` function, how will you know where the close braces are located? You can't. But if it's always located at the end, you can do:

```
def rebuilt(to_rebuilt):
    to_rebuilt = re.sub('__', '": {"', json.dumps(to_rebuilt))
    return re.sub('\}','}'*to_rebuilt.count("{"),to_rebuilt)

print(rebuilt(flatten(d)))
# prints {'a': 'A', 'b': {'c': 'BC', 'd': [4, 44, 444]}}
```

Comment: Thx, I'm not that much good at regular expression. Does your answer support arbitrary-level's nesting dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I made to handle lists with nested data structures as well:

```
def flatten_dict(src):
    """
    flatten dictionary to have depth of 1. (no nested lists or dictionaries)
    EX: {A: a, B: b, C: {D: d, E: e}, F: [g, h, i]} --> {A: a, B: b, C__D: d, C__E: e, "F,,0": g, "F,,1": h, "F,,2": i}
    """

    ret = {}
    for key, value in src.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            flat_value = flatten_dict(value)
            for inner_key, inner_value in flat_value.items():
                join_key = "__".join((key, inner_key))
                ret[join_key] = inner_value
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            flat_value = flatten_list(value)
            for inner_key, inner_value in flat_value.items():
                join_key = ",,".join((key, inner_key))
                ret[join_key] = inner_value
        else:
            ret[key] = value

    return ret

def flatten_list(src):
    """
    flat list is a dictionary!!
    """
    ret = {}
    for i in range(len(src)):
        if isinstance(src[i], dict):
            flat_value = flatten_dict(src[i])
            for inner_key, inner_value in flat_value.items():
                join_key = "__".join((str(i), inner_key))
                ret[join_key] = inner_value
        elif isinstance(src[i], list):
            flat_value = flatten_list(src[i])
            for inner_key, inner_value in flat_value.items():
                join_key = ",,".join((str(i), inner_key))
                ret[join_key] = inner_value
        else:
            ret[str(i)] = src[i]
    
    return ret
```

[Edit] The highly requested rebuilder for this flat dict

```
from itertools import takewhile
def rebuild_dict(src):
    ret = {}
    for key, value in src.items():
        rebuild_helper_dict(key, value, ret)

    return ret


def rebuild_helper_dict(key, value, result):
    split_index_dict = key.find("__")
    split_index_list = key.find(",,") 
    if split_index_dict == -1 and split_index_list == -1:
        result.update({key: value})
    else:
        if split_index_list == -1 or split_index_dict != -1 and split_index_dict < split_index_list:
            if isinstance(result.get(key[:split_index_dict]), type(None)):
                result.update({key[:split_index_dict]: {}}) # No dictionary made yet. Make it
            rebuild_helper_dict(key[split_index_dict + 2:], value, result[key[:split_index_dict]])

        else:
            if isinstance(result.get(key[:split_index_list]), type(None)):
                result.update({key[:split_index_list]: []})
            rebuild_helper_list(key[split_index_list + 2:], value, result[key[:split_index_list]])
            

            
def rebuild_helper_list(key, value, result):
    split_index_dict = key.find("__")
    split_index_list = key.find(",,")
    index = int(''.join(takewhile(str.isdigit, key)))
    if index > len(result): 
        result.extend([None]*(index - len(result))) # Grow list to size of this index
    if split_index_dict == -1 and split_index_list == -1:
        result.insert(index, value)
    else:
        if split_index_list == -1 or split_index_dict != -1 and split_index_dict < split_index_list:
            if isinstance(result[index], type(None)):
                result.insert(index, {}) # No dictionary made yet. Make it
            rebuild_helper_dict(key[split_index_dict + 2:], value, result[key[:split_index_dict]])

        else:
            if isinstance(result[index], type(None)):
                result.insert(index, [])
            rebuild_helper_list(key[split_index_list + 2:], value, result[index])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).